# Adding a xml to a LinearLayout item in android studio

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio

I have xml layout which includes a avatar picture a name and a textbox. These are all in one xml file.  I would like to add instances these programmically to a linear layout that is nested in a scoll view.  Here is my code.

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.include_message, null);
    LinearLayout stallWall = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.stallMessages);
```

R.layout.include_message = My xml
R.id.stallMessages = Linear Layout

I get no errors and i see no items being added.
I would like to read a array and put a include_message in for each message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would not recommend using x = y = z = a and so on. 
It may be working but it's not easy to read and understand. 
as codeMagic said, you should use addView() method to achieve this.

here's an example http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137

If you are trying to use a layout defined in an xml file, you can user LayoutInflater like this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourfile, null);
layout.addView(view);
```

Comment: I want to add one include to that, that example shows examples of dynamically adding elements.

Comment: Have you tried using LayoutInflater ?, you can create a view from that xml file like this View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ID, null); then you can add that view to your layout.

Comment: Yah i tried the method you showed me and a few others... Problem is i cannot put multiple things in one container... Here is my current code http://pastebin.com/ZjmMX0ig

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: GOT IT!!! THANKS SO MUCH!!! `final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stallMessages);

        // create the layout params that will be used to define how your
        // button will be displayed
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Create four
        for(int j=0;j<=4;j++) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stall_message, null);
            layout.addView(view);

        } `